# Xamarin forms Проблема подключение к MSSQL серверу

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Есть необходимость подключить Xamarin forms к MSSQL серверу напрямую. Пока без Web сервисов.
Данный пост говорит что это возможно.
[тут](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44392/connect-mobile-application-to-sql-server)

Делаю точно также.

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string str = @"Server=IP;Database=BASENAME;User Id=sa;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=true";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                //open connection
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
```

На connection.Open(); получаю такую ошибку.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  Message=System.Net.Security.Native assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+NetSecurityNative.ImportPrincipalName(Interop/NetSecurityNative/Status&,string,int,Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle&)
  at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle.CreatePrincipal (System.String name) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/Microsoft/Win32/SafeHandles/GssSafeHandles.cs:39 
  at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.String targetName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/Unix/SafeDeleteNegoContext.cs:46 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& context, System.String targetName, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal inFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& outFlags) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:166 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, System.String spn, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer[] inSecurityBufferArray, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outSecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:240 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.Byte[] serverName) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIProxy.cs:113 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength, System.Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObjectManaged.cs:240 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:6488 
System.Net.Security.Native assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+NetSecurityNative.ImportPrincipalName(Interop/NetSecurityNative/Status&,string,int,Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle&)
  at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle.CreatePrincipal (System.String name) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/Microsoft/Win32/SafeHandles/GssSafeHandles.cs:39 
  at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.String targetName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/Unix/SafeDeleteNegoContext.cs:46 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& context, System.String targetName, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal inFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& outFlags) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:166 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, System.String spn, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer[] inSecurityBufferArray, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outSecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:240 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.Byte[] serverName) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIProxy.cs:113 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength, System.Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObjectManaged.cs:240 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:6488
```

Что не так?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверил на сервере в локальной сети, все работает.
Ставим пакет во все проекты решения

[image: пакет]

Проверяем так

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var conString = "Data Source=192.168.0.250;Database=Chinook;" +
            "User ID=sa;Password=SqL17!Server;Connect Timeout=30;" +
            "Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;" +
            "MultiSubnetFailover=False";

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Artist";
            await con.OpenAsync();
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }

        Output.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

Работает (в манифесте андроид проекта ничего не менял).

[image: работа примера]

Comment: Сравнил Ваш коди и свой. Ошибка у меня была в строке подключения. Trusted_Connection=true. Если его убрать все работает. Спасибо!!!

Comment: @Manul74 пожалуйста. И пользуйтесь асинхронными возможностями, чтоб не блочить UI.

Comment: но мой код с такой строкой подключения  в winforms работает. Даже не мог подумать что там ошибка. Еще раз Спасибо.

Comment: Это быстрый набросок кода проверить работает ли. естественно в работе будет все правильно.